# How to search for Array with multiple search values in Postgresql using sequelize?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to search for an array of choices using sequelize to search in a postgreSql column that stores array of text.

I am able to search with one value, but when I give multiple values sequelize only returns a record if there is an exact match.

eg

```
id | keywords
1  | ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3']
2  | ['keyword1', 'keyword two']
```

using

```
find({
where : { keywords : {$contains: ['keyword1']} } })
```

returns both the records but

```
find({
where : { keywords : {$contains: ['keyword1','keyword2']} } })
```

returns only the first one even though 'keyword1' is present in both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
findAll({
  where: {
    keywords: {
      $contains: ['keyword1', 'keyword2']
    }
  }
})
```

because with `find()`, the result will be the first entry of the `Keywords` table with the `keyword1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the search is based on "AND" and not "OR",
Only if the array contains both the values will it be returned.

Search for $or operator in sequelize docs to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
         Tag.findAll({
            where: {
                name: {
                    [Op.any]: ['javascript','php']
                }
            }})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).